# Present from one VC's button to another VC makes SWrevealviewcontroller found nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am having an issue with **SWRevealViewController** getting **nil**,
Please see my below explanation.

**Explanation:**

I have 2 menus for my 2 screens **View1**, **View2**.
**View1** is a table view in which I have used custom cell, I have added one button in custom cell.
So, when I click on that button It jumps to the **View2**, But the slider navigation doesn't work.
Because 
`SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;` getting **nil** in **View2**

Here is my code which I have written in my `UITableViewCell` class

```
UIViewController *view = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
 View2* mapviewController = [view.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapView"];

[view presentViewController:mapviewController animated:NO completion:^{}];
```

Code which I have written in my **View2**

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if ( revealViewController ) {
    [self.btnMenu setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.btnMenu setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
    self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.size.width - 100;
}
```

It would be great if someone can help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Mihir Oza

Comment: SWRevealViewController only get if you make that VC as front view. why you needed that SWRevealViewController object in your presented VC ?

Comment: I added one button in my View1 to jump to Veiw2 with some data.

Comment: So how to pass my data from one VC to another VC ?

Comment: to pass data you dont required SWRevealViewController object simply you can pass it through your segue. By the way what you want to pass on next view ?

Comment: View 2 is a map screen and I am passing my coornidate through view1's tableviewcell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer,
With the help of Patrick I resolve that issue.

In my table view controller:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.rvc = self.revealViewController;
    cell.title.text = @"Your title";

    return cell;
}
```

In my custom cell:

```
    @interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

    @property (nonatomic,strong) SWRevealViewController *rvc;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

    @end  

    @implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTaped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonTaped:(void *)sender {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapView"];
    [self.rvc pushFrontViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Below is the full link may be it will useful for someone :
[Present from one VC to another](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/788)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your coordinate in tableViewDidSelectRow method like below :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MapViewController *objMapVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
    objMapVC.currentCord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(123.12345, 23.2345);
    [self presentViewController:objMapVC animated:YES completion:^{

    }];

}
```

or if you have button in your table cell so do assign index in your button like below :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.yourButton.tag = row;
    return cell;
}
```

Now in your button action do below thing :

```
-(IBAction)btnMapClick:(UIButton *)sender{

    MapViewController *objMapVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
    objMapVC.currentCord = Array[sender.tag];
    [self presentViewController:objMapVC animated:YES completion:^{

    }];

}
```

Also define one property in your MapViewController like below :

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCord;

@end
```

By doing above 2 step you can pass your selected co-ordinate to next MapVC.

Comment: `presentViewController` doesn't seem to work. and bye the way my button is in uitableviewcell not in viewcontroller.